# Switch in sign of second derivative about inflection point

Tags: calculus

I have just begun learning the basic concepts of Calculus. I understand that the inflection point is a point on the graph of the function where the concavity changes. I am having trouble understanding why the second derivative changes sign about the inflection point. (Or as I am thinking in my head) Why does the rate of change of slope shift sign about the inflection point? Also, why is it a necessary condition to identify the inflection point?

Comment: Note that in most cases when we have $f''(x_0)=0$ , we also have $f'''(x_0)\ne 0$ which also guarantees an inflection point at $x_0$. To get an intuition, imagine you drive exactly on the graph with a car in the direction of inceasing $x$-values. An inflection point means that we have to change from driving to the left (second derivate positive) to driving to the right (second derivate negative) or vice versa. At the inflection point , we drive straight (second derivate $0$).

Comment: You said it yourself: concavity changes. Concavity is measured by $f’’$